# Separate php logic from html document and maintain functionality

Tags: php

I'm having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around this problem.

I have an image map that I can click which sends various GET requests to my PHP script. My PHP script receives these GET requests and search through my MySQL Database to retrieve the appropriate information. My client is re-directed to this PHP page.

This all works and is great, but I need to incorporate Jquery for other functionality. So, I can't use a standalone PHP script.

My solution to this is use my imagemap to open up a HTML file instead, and use an include statement to incorporate my current PHP file.

However, I don't know how to include the PHP file if I need the GET requests created by clicking the image map.

How can I click on my image map, and be re-routed to a HTML page that displays the same information available from the GET requests in my PHP? I want to do this without creating multiple html files for such a small difference of one variable.

Comment: I'm afraid this is a very broad question. You need to post some code, and ask specifically in reference to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should try to use ajax-javascript to combine the php request with the javascript request and then redirect using the combined info.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using JSON to send the php data to JS and then displayed it from there.